# I'm scraping walmart but whenever I enter a paramter for the function with the URL of the search to scrape I simply get none when I try to print it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, web-scraping

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


context = ssl._create_unverified_context()


def PriceOfLegos(Site):
    price = []
    title = []
    LegoWebsite = Site
    uLegoWebsite = uReq(LegoWebsite, context=context)
    LegoWebsiteHTML = uLegoWebsite.read()
    uLegoWebsite.close()
    LegoWebsiteSoup = soup(LegoWebsiteHTML, "html.parser")
    for x in LegoWebsiteSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "visuallyhidden"}):
        text = x.get_text()
    if text[0] == "$":
        price.append(text[1:])
    for x in LegoWebsiteSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "product-title-link line-clamp line-clamp-2"}):
        title_text = x.get_text()
        title.append(title_text)
    for x in price:
        print("$", x, sep="")


z = PriceOfLegos("https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=Lego%20horse")
print(z)
```

The scraping works when the code is not a function and the LegoWebsite = a URL. The only problem is I want it to be more dynamic so i can any enter any Search URL on Walmart and it will display the price. The problem I'm facing is when I run this my output is "None".

Comment: your printing out 'z' and 'z' is been assigned to None since your 'PriceOfLegos' returns None

Comment: @MariosKeri
But I at the end of my function it says
```
for x in price:
        print("$", x, sep="")
```
So shouldn't z return the end of my function AKA print out the all x in prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable text never gets created cos is out of the loop

```
if text[0] == "$":
    price.append(text[1:])
```

and when you printing out your price list is empty since nothing gets appended
cos the:

```
if text[0] == "$":
```

never gets True cos text variable dose not exists for if statement

try this:

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


context = ssl._create_unverified_context()


def PriceOfLegos(Site):
    price = []
    title = []
    LegoWebsite = Site
    uLegoWebsite = uReq(LegoWebsite, context=context)
    LegoWebsiteHTML = uLegoWebsite.read()
    uLegoWebsite.close()
    LegoWebsiteSoup = soup(LegoWebsiteHTML, "html.parser")
    for x in LegoWebsiteSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "visuallyhidden"}):
        text = x.get_text()
        if text[0] == "$":
            price.append(text[1:])
    for x in LegoWebsiteSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "product-title-link line-clamp line-clamp-2"}):
        title_text = x.get_text()
        title.append(title_text)
    for x in price:
        print("$", x, sep="")


PriceOfLegos("https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=Lego%20horse")
```

Comment: Hey, This worked thanks. The last thing I did was to put this out of the function
```
for x in z:
    print("$", x, sep="")
```